# Associating two models in a way both models' attributes are always pulled together in any view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, associations

I'm building a tech-specific pricegrabber-like web app, and I have a model that carries params that are common in all products. This model is called Product. Then I have one model for each type of product that I'm going to work with, for example, I'm now trying to build the first specific model, which is Videocard. So, the Product model always must have one Specific model, in this case Product-Videocard.

At this moment I'm stuck finding a way to make a product and a specific model always come tied together whenever I reach to them, be it in an index view, show view, `form_for`, a search, etc. But I can't picture in my head  how a form will create an item and its specifications and insert a foreign key into another model with only one submit request.

Below are both models and the migrations for each:

```
class Product < ApplicationRecord
  #belongs_to :productable, :polymorphic => true

  has_one :videocard, dependent: :destroy

  # Comment for this Stackoverflow question: the way I'm thinking I      
  # should have to make tons of has_one associations, for the other
  # products. Is there a DRY way to do this?


  has_many :prices, through: :stores

  validates :platform, presence: { message: "should be specified." }
  validates :name, presence: { message: "should be specified." }

  validates_associated :videocard
end

class Videocard < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :product
end
```

Migrations (shortened to make this question as clear as possible):

```
class CreateProducts < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    create_table :products do |t|

      t.references :productable, polymorphic: true, index: true

      t.string :name
      t.string :image
      t.string :partnum
      t.string :manufacturer
      t.string :platform #mobile, desktop, server, laptop

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end

class CreateVideocards < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    create_table :videocards do |t|

      t.references :product, index: true

      t.integer :memory
      t.string :interface

      # [...lots of attributes...]

      t.integer :displayport 
      t.integer :minidisplayport
      t.integer :tdp

      t.timestamps

    end
  end
end
```

Also how can I make it so that Product only needs one `has_one` association, instead of using multiple ones. Remember that Videocard will have one type of specification, Memory will have other, and so on.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I'd recommend reading http://catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html. We don't really care whether you're new to programming, we just want well-researched and well-asked questions.

Comment: You probably want [`has_many :through`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html).

Comment: I thought of has_many :through, but at the end I can't picture it well, since Product will have Videocard one time, then in another situation it will be linked to Memory, then to Processor in another...

I also think that by inverting that association making Videocard has_one :product I'd be messing with other associations that has_one :product via the polymorphic association (such as Builds and Stores).

Comment: When I say I'm new to programming it isn't to grovel or any thing like that, but actually to put things in a context where people will know there might be a lack of strictly technical questions and terms due to that situation (although I have researched about the related subject).

Comment: what you are saying about the model only having one other model makes no sense. There are more than one video cards, right? Just because there is only one video card model does not make it a has_one relationship.

Comment: Search for has_many :through

Comment: Well, I thought has_one association meant that one instance of a Model can only have one instance of a certain other Model. One product can only have one single list of specifications (since it relates to one single part number)